# Commutator Subgroup is Normal Subgroup of Kernel of Homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, normal-subgroups

Please help to understand this problem.

> Let $G$ be a group, $H$ an abelian group, $\phi : G \rightarrow H$ a homomorphism. Show that $C(G) \lhd \mathrm{Ker}(\phi)$

I must be misunderstanding something, because what if we have the natural (bijective) homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$. Then the kernel of the homomorphism is $0$ but the commutator subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ is $\mathbb{Z}$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the commutator subgroup of an abelian group? What are the elements of the form $ghg^{-1}h^{-1}$ in an abelian group?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems as if you are misunderstanding the definition of the commutator. It is not the center of the group.

Many times denoted $[G,G]$, it is defined to be the subgroup generated by the set $\{xyx^{-1}y^{-1} : x, y \in G\}$, where I am using multiplicative notation.

In your example $\mathbb{Z}$, an element in the commutator will be, for example with $x = 5$ and $y = 7$: $5 + 7 - 5 - 7$. You should be able to answer PVAL's question above, and this should give an indication of how to solve the problem.

Comment: The subgroup generated by such expressions!

Comment: That is hardly a subgroup!

Comment: @TedShifrin Ack! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

*Claim* If $x=[a,b]$ then $\varphi(x)=[\varphi(a),\varphi(b)]$.

*Proof* `[insert proof here]`

*Corollary* For every group morphism $\eta :G\to H$ with $H$ abelian, $[G,G]\subseteq \ker \eta$.

Comment: This is related to a theorem that every normal subgroup has the commutator as a subset. In fact, because it is a theorem that N is a normal subgroup iff it is the kernel of a group homomorphism, it follows that one can deduce from your corollary that every normal subgroup must have the commutator as a subset.

Answer (score 3):

If $x\in C(G)$ then $x$ is of the form $x=aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ for some $a,b \in G$. Now $\phi (x)= \phi(a)\phi(b)\phi(a)^{-1}\phi(b)^{-1}$ is in $H$, and since $H$ is abelian we have $\phi(x)=\phi(a)\phi(a)^{-1}\phi(b)\phi(b)^{-1}=1$ and thus $x \in \ker(\phi)$.

Comment: You perhaps meant $x\in \ker \phi$.

Comment: @Diogenes : of course. thanks!